# Satellite's EO sensor footprint on ground

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, sensors, remote-sensing, rotation-sequences

I'm a student and I'm trying to compute the footprint of a generic EO sensor starting from sensor's characteristics and position and velocity vector of my satellite in ECEF coordinates.
I followed [this tutorial of Stephen Hartzell](https://stephenhartzell.medium.com/satellite-line-of-sight-intersection-with-earth-d786b4a6a9b6) to compute the satellite line-of-sight intersection with Earth and validate the results comparing with the ones from STK.

It seems to work well when the satellite is Nadir pointing: the results (slant range, point on earth coordinates) differs about $10^{-8}$ from the STK ones. However, when I apply a pitch or roll rotation to the sensor boresight, the slant computed differs 27 meters from the STK ones with consequent significant errors (0.1°) to the latitude and longitude points computed from the intersection point coordinates.

To describe the procedure in detail, I've defined a unit vector pointing toward the Earth $(z = \frac{\llap{-}r}{|r|})$ from my ECEF coordinate. Therefore, I've moved that from ECEF to the satellite body coordinate system with the appropriate rotation matrix, and then I've applied my pitch/roll rotations around the proper axis. At this point, I converted the rotated pointing vector in ECEF coordinates, and I’ve applied the intersection procedure shown above.

Do you think this procedure is correct or there is another one more effective?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you calculate the influence of the atmosphere to the light from Earth surface to the sensor?

Comment: Please define your acronyms. EO can mean electro-optical, Earth observing, or maybe something else.

Comment: No, moreover I'm considering a propagation with only the effects of J2 .

Comment: You're right, I mean electro-optical (with a rectangular footprint) but I'm also considering an Earth observation mission.

Comment: Are you assuming the same ellipsoid as your reference?  27 metre is much less than 0.1°.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's what i'm asking myself because in STK (I'm not more pratic) I assume it's WGS84, therefore  I've used the WGS-84 equatorial and polar radius for my ellipsoid equation. However, the difference between my slant range and the STK's one is -3.970819193455100e-04 metres when the satellite is Nadir pointing. In fact, the error in detic latitude and longitude is of the order of -1e-09 deg. So it's working. Instead, when I apply a rotation (30° roll for example) the slant error is 27 metres and thus the detic latitude error is 0.12° while -0.019° is the longitude one.

Comment: Moreover, I've tried to use the same slant from STK to compute the intersection in the 30° roll case but the found coordinates lead me to the same lat and long error. Instead if I use the same intersection point coordinates, the lat and long values are the same. In conclusion I think that there's a problem in computing the correct rotated unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem: it must be taken into account a yaw angle for the yaw steering maneuver.

Comment: can you please describe your approach? Are you applying the intersection method for nadir as well as unit vectors corresponding to FOV or BeamWidth to compute the footprint?